# display the file upload percentage of a file with primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I would like to display the percentage of fileupload while I am uploading files (I chose "true" so I can upload mutiple files)

my xhtml code is:

```
   <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" multiple="true" />
```

I have a bean

```
public class FileUploadController { 

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  

    System.out.println("handleFileUpload");


        try {
            copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
            uplFile = event.getFile();
            fileName = uplFile.getFileName();

            renderFileName = true;
            List<UploadedFile> files = uploadBean.getUploadedFiles();
            if (files == null){
                files = new ArrayList<UploadedFile>();
            }
            files.add(uplFile);

            uploadBean.setUploadedFiles(files);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}  
...
```

The difficulties are for me:

1)  to get the size of the file in a java Bean (they appear on screen) AFTER I chose the files and BEFORE the upload event is fired  so I can compute the ratio of bits uploaded for each file against the initial bits size

2) I can compute the bits uploaded for uplFile = event.getFile(), I think I can even even put them in a Map and use  to refresh the display, the problem is that I woudl like to display these numbers on the progression bar, or if not possible, next to it. However, I am no able do do it for the current time.

Any hints ?

Comment: Do you use Primefaces 4? I couldn't test it, but maybe it is already offered? I just had a look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf

Comment: Yes I am using Primefaces 4, as you can test, you have a progress bar but not a percentage computed